# How can I deploy php code from svn to production linux sever using jenkins from localhost of local machine?

Tags: php, jenkins, deployment

I have done the configuration for SVN jenkins,but still its not working ,its not done the build on svn repository though its showing build is done.

I need to set up configuration to deploy code on svn to production Linux server ,I'm doing this all on my local machine with localhost.
which pulgin should I use to deploy php code form svn.
I have install most of the php plugins in jenkins.
only configuration is remain to deploy code on Linux server .

Comment: more data like console output might be useful

Comment: I'm new to jenkins,I was trying to configure php project through jenkins dashboard not in cmd .but no any idea about how to deploy php code on server.

Comment: what kind of job did you use ? freestyle? if yes , share ad list the project configuration. without any information of what you did it is hard to help

Comment: yes ,i have select freestyle ,but no idea about next steps,means to deploy project what exactly I have to do in jenkins.How to create war file,or how to use this in jenkins tp deploy the project or how to use option copy artifacts..

Comment: Source Code Management >in that i choose svn

Comment: Source Code Management >in that i choose svn then pass Repository URL and credentials.Local module directory is "." and Repository depth > infinity . in Build section i select copy artifacts fron another poject and i have written the name of the project which  i already set in jenkins ,for that Artifacts to copy  I gave **\*.war in text box and  Target directory as production server project link,

Comment: in Post-build Actions section  i select Archive the artifacts option and for  Files to archive I have given **\*.war in textbox then I in deploy war to container option in WAR/EAR files text box I have given **\*.war and in Context path i have given local workspace path in  Containers i have selected tomcat 7 and pass Credentials and Tomcat URL I have pass http://localhost:8080/

Comment: but its not creating any war file ,should I have to download all the php realted softwares like PHPMD ,phpcb etc..?